# How to test a wrapper of third party lib?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, publish-subscribe, gcloud

```
class GPublisher():

    def __init__(self, topic_name):
        self.publisher = PublisherClient()
        self.project_id = settings.project_id
        self.topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(
            self.project_id, topic_name)

    def publish(self, data):
        message_future = self.publisher.publish(self.topic_path, data=data)
        message_future.add_done_callback(self.callback)

    def callback(self, message_future):
        if message_future.exception(timeout=30):
            print('Publishing message on {} threw an Exception {}.'.format(
                self.topic_name, message_future.exception()))
        else:
            print(message_future.result())
```

How can I do an unit test for that class? And how it make sure the class always run properly since it is not a real one?

Answer (score 0):

If you inject dependencies you can easily replace third-party module with mock for unit tests

```
class GPublisher():

def __init__(self, topic_name, publisher_client):
    self.publisher = publisher_client
    self.project_id = settings.project_id
    self.topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(
        self.project_id, topic_name)
```

and in unit test

```
GPublisher("topic_name", mock_publish_client)
```